# Loop for copying range from other sheet with if statement

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

I'm new to VBA and can't figure out how to modify this code, to get value of range from other sheet.

```
Sub dav()
    For i = 1 To 10
        If Sheets("yan").Range("A" & i).Value = Sheets("fev").Range("A" & i).Value Then
            Sheets("yan").Range("B" & i:"O" & i).Value = Sheets("fev").Range("C" & i:"P" & i).Value
        End If
    Next i
End Sub
```

I have no idea how to correct this part `Range("B" & i:"O" & i)`.

[image: this is two sheets]

Comment: Perhaps `Range("B" & i & ":O" & i)`

Comment: thank you. yes it works . but filters only first cell(A1)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to avoid using Select in Excel VBA](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10714251/how-to-avoid-using-select-in-excel-vba)

Comment: Where was filtering involved here? @Dominique where is Select involved here? OP: your code checks if the same row's A-value is the same on both sheets, clearly that's the case for the first one but yan's A2's value is in row 5 of fev's sheet.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to match the value in yan to column A in fev to find the correct row to copy.

```vb
Option Explicit

Sub dav()

    Dim r As Long, s As String, lastrow As Long
    Dim wsFev As Worksheet, v, n As Long
    Set wsFev = Sheets("fev")
    
    With Sheets("yan")
        lastrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
        For r = 1 To lastrow
            s = .Range("A" & r)
            v = Application.Match(s, wsFev.Range("A:A"), 0)
            If Not IsError(v) Then
                'copy columns B:O
                wsFev.Range("B" & v).Resize(, 14).Copy .Range("B" & r)
                n = n + 1
            End If
        Next
    End With
    MsgBox n & " rows copied from Sheet fev", vbInformation

End Sub
```